# Connecting solar panel to breadboard

Tags: wiring, breadboard, solar-energy

I apologize if this is foolish question, but I wanted to know how to connect a solar panel(that has no wires) to a breadboard. I wanted to test it out, but I am confused how to do it. Thanks for any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to solder wires to the panel.

Comment: Have you tried soldering some wires?

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if I should solder them, and if it would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Solder a wire to each of the gold contacts. You may need to scratch off any coating over them first. Then you could connect it as normal.

Comment: That, or spring-loaded contacts and a fixture